# Symfony visual server configuration tester

Tags: php, symfony

Im going through Symfony tutorial:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

I already installed it and created my project on web server. the application name is 'blog' and it is on remote server. However, this tutorial tells me that...

```
Symfony2 comes with a visual server configuration tester to help make sure your Web server and PHP are configured to use Symfony. Use the following URL to check your configuration:

http://localhost/config.php
```

So if my 'blog' folder is under `http://www.awesome_server.com/~my_login/blog` what URI should I use to perform this test?

Answer (score 1):

If http://www.awesome_server.com/~my_login/blog is pointing to the web folder of your Symfony project, you should use http://www.awesome_server.com/~my_login/blog/config.php. If not, you should use http://www.awesome_server.com/~my_login/blog/web/config.php, but you should know that when you try to access to this script in a remote server, you will receive a message as below:

```
This script is only accessible from localhost.
```

However, you could open the config.php and add the IP address of your remote server in the array or delete the following code:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

For security reasons, don't forget to change the file after you check your configuration, because is not recommended to leave all people which access to this file to see your configuration.